# "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed"

Tags: bug, editing

Any post I try to edit on the main site (including tag wikis; excluding my own q&a) gives me this plaintext message on its own page:

> This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed

Why is this?

Comment: In what post does it happen?

Comment: @nicael **Anything.** Even tag wikis.

Comment: Can you edit this post? Does it only happen on the main site?

Comment: @nicael Yes, only the main site. And only on Lifehacks.

Comment: Does it happen to your posts on the main site?

Comment: @nicael I added more details to my question.

Comment: I was getting this on my own posts but I waited a few minutes and then it started working.

Comment: Didn't happen to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The bug here is that the copy you're seeing is incorrect - what you should see is something like:</strike>

> You cannot suggest more edits until your previous edits have been reviewed.

I was incorrect - while the bug was in the copy, it is of a different nature; it should say:

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your [edit history](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

One issue is that there're no throttles on suggesting edits, so you can suggest quite a few before getting any feedback that they've been rejected.  And then an auto-ban happens.

Going to add that throttling tonight.

Comment: How long will this last? Thanks!

Comment: It usually lasts a week, but you've gained enough rep to edit without suggesting, so it doesn't matter now.

Comment: I'll wait it out. I was hoping to be adding tag wikis about now...